# Different output for same code in C++14 and c++17

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17

I am getting different answers for the same c++ code but in different versions of c++
i.e. c++14 and c++17

What are the changed made into c++17 from c++14 because of which I am getting different answers ?

(Specifically related to this question)

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i = 1;
    cout << i++ <<" "<< i-- << " " << i--;
    return 0;
}

/*
* Output in c++17
*   1 2 1
*
* Output in c++14
*  -1 0 1
*
*/
```

Comment: Isn't it undefined behavior?

Comment: @DYZ Yes, it's UB - multiple unsequenced modifications to the variable, `i`.

Comment: It is. Changing a variable while using it in the same command is undefined behavior and the result can't be predicted. The change might be because of compiler core changes.

Comment: `cout << i++ <<" "<< i-- << " " << i--;` looks like [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) to me. So you never had any reasonable expectation for any specific outcome. *Any* result is permissible.

Comment: fwiw, even if this was well defined you shouldn't be writing code like that

Comment: But wasn't order of evaluation fixed with C++17? Or does it not cover operators?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen It was fixed for this operator.  Just closed as a dupe to the canonical.

Comment: Not an *exact* duplicate, but very related: [Undefined behavior and sequence points](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4176328/10871073).

Answer (score 1):

C++17 changed the rules for the order of evaluation of some expression.

Let's rewrite the expression to its equivalent in function calls:

```
std::operator<<(std::operator<<(std::cout.operator<<(i++), " ").operator<<(i--), " ").operator<<(i--);
```

In C++14, the compiler was permitted to evaluate from right to left, or in ony nested order

To support chaining properly, [C++17 states that such expressions are sequenced](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order).

For example, `std::operator<<(std::cout.operator<<(i++), " ").operator<<(i--)` C++17 requires that `i++` is evaluated before `i--`.